# Resizing an image in swing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, bufferedimage, imageicon

I have snippet of code that I am using for the purpose of resizing an image to a curtain size (I want to change the resolution to something like 200 dpi). Basically the reason I need it is because I want to display the image that the user have picked (somewhat large) and then if the user approves I want to display the same image in a different place but using a smaller resolution. Unfortunately, if I give it a large image nothing appears on the screen. Also, if I change

```
imageLabel.setIcon(newIcon);
```

to

```
imageLabel.setIcon(icon);
```

I get the image to display but not in the correct resolution that's how I know that I have a problem inside this snipper of code and not somewhere else.

```
Image img = icon.getImage();

BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
boolean myBool = g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100, null);
System.out.println(myBool);
ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(bi);
imageLabel.setIcon(newIcon);
submitText.setText(currentImagePath);
imageThirdPanel.add(imageLabel);
```

Comment: 1) Did you have a question? 2) Note that everything up to `ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(bi);` is AWT, not Swing. 3) It is 'Swing', not 'swing' 4) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Okay. I'm not displaying the whole code because it's too long. Also, I'm not sure why you say it's Swing and not swing (that's what I got from the auto complete when I entered the tag - I don't see how that is my fault). I think it's SSCCE. Like I said the rest of the code works I'm sure there is a problem in this snippet of code. Probably when I draw the Image, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: *"I think it's SSCCE."*  You think wrong.  Please read the document.

Comment: Why don't you use `Image.getScaledInstance()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
    private BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int width, int height, int type) throws IOException {  
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, type);  
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();  
        g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, width, height, null);  
        g.dispose();  
        return resizedImage;  
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

You don't really have to care about the details of scaling images. The Image class has already a method `getScaledInstance(int width, int height, int hints)` designed for this purpose. 
Java documentation says:

> Creates a scaled version of this image. A new Image object is returned
>   which will render the image at the specified width and height by
>   default. The new Image object may be loaded asynchronously even if the
>   original source image has already been loaded completely. If either
>   the width or height is a negative number then a value is substituted
>   to maintain the aspect ratio of the original image dimensions.

And you can use it like this:

```
// Scale Down the original image fast
Image scaledImage = imageToScale.getScaledInstance(newWidth, newHighth, Image.SCALE_FAST);
// Repaint this component
repaint();
```

Check [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Imagescale.htm) for a complete example.

Comment: If a proportional scale is needed pass `-1` as argument for the measure that should follow the other. For example, if you want to scale based on width only you would call something like `anImage.getScaledInstance(150, -1, java.awt.Image.SCALE_FAST)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this CODE to resize image :

```
public static Image scaleImage(Image original, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    //do nothing if new and old resolutions are same
    if (original.getWidth() == newWidth && original.getHeight() == newHeight) {
        return original;
    }

    int[] rawInput = new int[original.getHeight() * original.getWidth()];
    original.getRGB(rawInput, 0, original.getWidth(), 0, 0, original.getWidth(), original.getHeight());
    int[] rawOutput = new int[newWidth * newHeight];
    // YD compensates for the x loop by subtracting the width back out
    int YD = (original.getHeight() / newHeight) * original.getWidth() - original.getWidth();
    int YR = original.getHeight() % newHeight;
    int XD = original.getWidth() / newWidth;
    int XR = original.getWidth() % newWidth;
    int outOffset = 0;
    int inOffset = 0;
    for (int y = newHeight, YE = 0; y > 0; y--) {
        for (int x = newWidth, XE = 0; x > 0; x--) {
            rawOutput[outOffset++] = rawInput[inOffset];
            inOffset += XD;
            XE += XR;
            if (XE >= newWidth) {
                XE -= newWidth;
                inOffset++;
            }
        }
        inOffset += YD;
        YE += YR;
        if (YE >= newHeight) {
            YE -= newHeight;
            inOffset += original.getWidth();
        }
    }
    return Image.createRGBImage(rawOutput, newWidth, newHeight, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example is given here :

2D-Graphics/LoadImageandscaleit.htm">http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261_2D-Graphics/LoadImageandscaleit.htm

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/ImagegetScaledInstanceintwidthintheightinthints.htm